# Unable to modify a line for recursive call written in python

Tags: python, recursion, web-scraping

I can make recursive call with Python and BeautifulSoup to parse links but in case of using xpath to do the same i got stuck. Here is the code that I tried with:

```
import requests
from lxml import html
pages = set()
def getLinks(Url):
    global pages
    page= requests.get("http://en.wikipedia.org"+Url)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
    link=tree.xpath("//a/@href")
    for "href" in link:
        if "href" in link:
            if "href" not in pages:
                newpage=link
                print(newpage)
                pages.add(newpage)
                getLinks(newpage)
getLinks("/wiki/Julian_Ashton")
```

Comment: Remove double quotes from for loop declaration, you meant href?

Comment: Thanks postoronnim for your reply. You write the answer in such a way so that I can accept it. It's working man.

Comment: Just upvote, there is already an answer. Tks

Comment: The button holding upvote option is grayed out at my end. I looked for it in the first place.

Comment: @Mth80. You shall accept the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove redundant if statement in line `if "href" in link:` since in you xpath expression you have already selected all a href attributes from the page.
You can rewrite your code like this:

```
for link in tree.xpath("//a/@href"):
    if link not in pages:
        newpage=link
        print(newpage)
        pages.add(newpage)
        getLinks(newpage)
```

Comment: Dear Vlad, the answer you provided not only remove the redundancy but also brings the result the way I expected. So, I consider your answer the best and accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Remove that double quotes from your for loop `for "href" in link:`
This will work for you

```
link=tree.xpath("//a/@href")
    for href in link:
        if "href" in link:
            if "href" not in pages:
                newpage=link
                print(newpage)
```

Comment: Dear Prabhakar I corrected my written code the way you suggested but it doesn't bring any result.

Comment: @Mth80. I just notified about the double quotes.. Other than that I believe no changes required in your code